# Why does a function returning float not work with void* callback?

Tags: c, callback

In the code below, why does `int` work but not `float`? Results are below.

voidptr.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void* (*Fn) ();

int Fun()
{
    return 5;
}

float fFun()
{
    return 5.0;
}


void callfun(Fn f)
{
    printf ("%d \n", f());
}

void callffun(Fn f)
{
    printf ("%f \n", f());
}



int main()
{

    callfun(Fun); // works
    callffun(fFun); // --> doesnt work ??
    printf ("%f", fFun()); // works

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
5 
0.000000 
5.000000
```

Comment: It doesn't really "work". You just shot in direction foot and happened to hit one of the toes that was already numb from last night's booze.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  Compile-time error, runtime error?  Please be specific.

Comment: It doesn't work.  If you turn compiler warnings up (which you should do), you'll see that it doesn't compile cleanly: http://ideone.com/Yh7SyT.  You should pay attention to compiler messages.

Comment: the result is in the bottom it returns 0.000 instead of 5.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast a `void*` to a `float` and expect it to work.

A better solution would be to have your callback functions return void, but accept a void * as a location to drop the return value:

```
typedef void (*Fn) (void *);

void Fun(void *ptr)
{
    *(int *)ptr = 5;
}

void fFun(void *ptr)
{
    *(float *)ptr = 5.0;
}

void callfun(Fn f)
{
    int num;
    f(&num);
    printf ("%d \n", num);
}

void callffun(Fn f)
{
    float num;
    f(&num);
    printf ("%f \n", num);
}
```

This still has problems - you would need to know in advance what kind of variable the pointer passed to the callback was pointing to.

Comment: Below two works though it is not a good idea to return a stack ptr. I still wonder why int worked in my first example ?       float* fFun()
{
    float *f;
    f = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float));
    *f = 5.0;
    return f;
}

float* fFun()
{
    float f = 5.0;
    return &f;
}

Comment: @purpletech: That code is broken. You throw away the return value from `malloc` and then you return a float when you said you'd return a `float *`. What you probably want is something like `float *f; f = malloc(sizeof(float)); *f = 5.0; return f;`.

Comment: +1 thx. if you notice carefully, i provided the same malloc solution you provided, but I wonder if i can return a  ptr in the stack like float* fFun() { float f = 5.0; return &f; } . It works but its unsafe right ?

Comment: also, My research is to find a generic return type. Is void * the best possible type?

Comment: never mind i found the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185773/why-its-not-safe-to-return-value-on-function-stack/5185907#5185907

Comment: I don't see how that applies here. The functions I wrote aren't returning a stack pointer. They're taking in a pointer which may or may not be on the calling function's stack, and writing a value to it. That's totally safe.

Answer (score 3):

You're lying to the compiler. The results are unpredictable.

Comment: what do you mean ? how can i make a call back generic so i can return int and float ?

Comment: @purpletech: You can't, because there's nothing useful you could do with the result.  At best you might consider returning some kind of variant object (a struct containing a union and an enum/flag should suffice).

Comment: @purpletech: How would the caller know whether it got back an int or a float? Perhaps you want a struct that contains an int, a float, and some indicator of which one was returned?

Comment: well, my engine is only supposed to call the callback and the return value is given back to the user that knows what type it is, he writes a function with my result. is returning void* not possible or what ?

Comment: Returning a `void *` is possible, but only to cast to some other kind of pointer. You'll need rules to determine the lifetime of the object it points to. (Who allocates it? Who frees it?)